# No intent receiver set Urban AirShip

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I do receive the push messages but whenever I click on them inside the notificationbar this logcat appears and the notification dissapears...

This is my logcat output:

```
 05-31 16:49:47.165: D/Test - UALib(20523): No intent receiver set, not sending ACTION_NOTIFICATION_OPENED
```

Here is my manifest structure:

```
        <category android:name="com.test.push" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service
    android:name="com.urbanairship.push.PushService"
    android:label="Push Notification Service" />
<service
    android:name="com.urbanairship.push.PushWorkerService"
    android:label="Push Notification Worker Service" />
<service
    android:name="com.urbanairship.analytics.EventService"
    android:label="Event Service" />

<provider
    android:name="com.urbanairship.UrbanAirshipProvider"
    android:authorities="com.test.push.urbanairship.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:multiprocess="true" />

<activity
    android:name="com.test.push.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name="com.test.push.SettingsActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" />
<activity
    android:name="com.test.push.ChooseClass"
    android:label="@string/app_name" />
</application>
```

This here is my MyApplication.java:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
AirshipConfigOptions options = AirshipConfigOptions
        .loadDefaultOptions(this);
options.developmentAppKey = "1234567890";
options.developmentAppSecret = "1234567890";
options.productionAppKey = "";
options.productionAppSecret = "";
options.gcmSender = "1234567890";
options.transport = "gcm";
options.inProduction = false;

UAirship.takeOff(this, options);
PushManager.enablePush();
}
}
```

And this is my IntentReceiver.java:

```
public class IntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context aContext, Intent aIntent) {
String action = aIntent.getAction();

if (action.equals(PushManager.ACTION_PUSH_RECEIVED)) {
    logPushExtras(aIntent);
} else if (action.equals(PushManager.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_OPENED)) {
    logPushExtras(aIntent);

    Intent launch = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    launch.setClass(UAirship.shared().getApplicationContext(),
            MainActivity.class);

    launch.putExtra("push_message",
            aIntent.getStringExtra(PushManager.EXTRA_ALERT));
    launch.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    UAirship.shared().getApplicationContext().startActivity(launch);
} else if (action.equals(PushManager.ACTION_REGISTRATION_FINISHED)) {
    Logger.info("device registrated, APID="
            + aIntent.getStringExtra(PushManager.EXTRA_APID)
            + ", valid="
            + aIntent.getBooleanExtra(
                    PushManager.EXTRA_REGISTRATION_VALID, false));
}
}

private void logPushExtras(Intent intent) {
Set<String> keys = intent.getExtras().keySet();
for (String key : keys) {

    List<String> ignoredKeys = (List<String>) Arrays.asList(
            "collapse_key", "from", PushManager.EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_ID,
            PushManager.EXTRA_PUSH_ID, PushManager.EXTRA_ALERT);
    if (ignoredKeys.contains(key)) {
        continue;
    }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was, I was missing the following line inside my `MyApplication.java` file:

```
    PushManager.shared().setIntentReceiver(IntentReceiver.class);
```

All the rest was correct. It's now working perfectly.

Comment: Where you keep this statement in java file ? Actually I keep this statement in onCreate(), but not working.

Answer (score 1):

And i was missing to specify Application's `android:name` attribute in my manifest file-

```
<application
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
  android:allowClearUserData="true"
  android:enabled="true" 
  android:name=".MyMainApplication">

  <activity>
  Some Activity
  </activity>

</application>
```